# Select a specific line of an array in a for loop

Tags: arrays, bash, for-loop

I have an array with multiple lines, and I would like to select a specific line of the array in a for loop. And then use the data in the selected line for some analysis in the for loop.

```
ARRAY=(A1,A2 
B1,B2 
C1,C2)
```

When I applied the below code, I can assign "B1" to Trait1 and "B2" to Trait2. This works for j=1 or j=3 as well.

```
j=2
echo ${ARRAY[$j-1]}
Trait1="$(echo ${ARRAY[$j-1]} | cut -d',' -f1)"
Trait2="$(echo ${ARRAY[$j-1]} | cut -d',' -f2)"
echo $Trait1
echo $Trait2
```

Ultimately, I want to put the above code in a for loop. But this failed.

```
nLine=3
for j in $(eval echo "{1..$nLine}")
do
    Trait1="$(echo ${ARRAY[$j-1]} | cut -d',' -f1)"
    Trait2="$(echo ${ARRAY[$j-1]} | cut -d',' -f2)"
    echo $Trait1
    echo $Trait2
done

-bash: 1 2 3-1: syntax error in expression (error token is "2 3-1")
-bash: 1 2 3-1: syntax error in expression (error token is "2 3-1")
```

Thank you.

Comment: Why not just `${ARRAY[j]}` or `${ARRAY[$j]}`? They are "lines", by the way, they are separate elements, so `${ARRAY[0]}` is `A!,A2`, `${ARRAY[1]}` is `B1,B2`, etc.

Comment: When you access an array without an index, it's equivalent to `${ARRAY[0]}`

Comment: There's no newlines with shell word splitting here

Comment: Thank you all. I can use the array indexing operator outside the for loop. But I got an error when I put the same code in the loop as explained in the revised question.

Comment: the updated/edited `for` loop block of code works for me (generates `A1\nA2\nB1\nB2\nC1\nC2`); what version of `bash` are you running? (`bash --version`)

Comment: -bash-4.2$ bash --version
GNU bash, version 4.2.46(2)-release (x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu)
Copyright (C) 2011 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
License GPLv3+: GNU GPL version 3 or later <http://gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Keeping the current code design I'd probably want to use [parameter expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Parameter-Expansion.html) to break the array element into its 2 components ...

Data setup:

```
$ ARRAY=(A1,A2
B1,B2
C1,C2)
$ typeset -p ARRAY
declare -a ARRAY=([0]="A1,A2" [1]="B1,B2" [2]="C1,C2")
```

Quick demo of parameter expansion to break array element into parts:

```
$ x=${ARRAY[0]}
$ echo ${x}
A1,A2
$ echo ${x%,*}
A1
$ echo ${x#*,}
A2
```

Updating the PO's `for` loop to use parameter expansion, and replacing the `eval/echo/j-1` with something a bit easier to read:

```
nLine=3
for (( j=0 ; j<nLine ; j++ ))
do
    Trait1="${ARRAY[${j}]%,*}"
    Trait2="${ARRAY[${j}]#*,}"
    echo "${Trait1}"
    echo "${Trait2}"
done
```

Generates the output:

```
A1
A2
B1
B2
C1
C2
```

Comment: Thanks. This is very helpful.

Answer (score 0):

The way you're using it, you should have a single string, not an array.

```
ARRAY='A1,A2 
B1,B2 
C1,C2'
```

Then when you use it as a here-string input to `sed`, it will receive multiple lines of input, and you can select the line you want with `${j}p`.

As mentioned in the comments, this seems like a convoluted way to access array elements. You can simply use the shell's built-in array indexing operator.

Answer (score 0):

Array assignments

```
ARRAY=(A1,A2
B1,B2
C1,C2)
```

and

```
ARRAY=(A1,A2 B1,B2 C1,C2)
```

are equivalent and both define an array with 3 elements: `A1,A2`, `B1,B2`, and `C1,C2`. Space(s), tab(s) and new-line(s) are used to separate array elements in compound assignments.

A `for` loop can be used to traverse an array:

```
#  "${ARRAY[@]}" expands each element of ARRAY to a separate word
for elm in "${ARRAY[@]}"; do
    # The value of the array element accessed is "$elm"
done
```

Or, using the alternate form of the `for` loop:

```
#  ${#ARRAY[*]} expands to the number of elements in the ARRAY
for ((j = 0; j < ${#ARRAY[*]}; ++j)); do
    # Array element can be referenced using ${ARRAY[j]}
done
```

assuming there is no gap between indices (*bash* allows an array with "holes").

*Here strings*, a variant of *here documents*, and `read` builtin with `IFS` variable can be used to parse the elements of the array:

```
IFS=, read Trait1 Trait2 <<< ${ARRAY[j]}
```

Here the `IFS` is used with the value `,` to cut the array element into `Trait1` and `Trait2` when there is a `,`.

So, a sample program to demonstrate all of these may be:

```
#!/bin/bash

ARRAY=(A1,A2 
B1,B2 
C1,C2)

for elem in "${ARRAY[@]}"; do
    IFS=, read Trait1 Trait2 <<< $elem
    printf "%s\n%s\n" "$Trait1" "$Trait2"
done
```

or,

```
#!/bin/bash

ARRAY=(A1,A2 
B1,B2 
C1,C2)

for ((j = 0; j < ${#ARRAY[*]}; ++j)); do
    IFS=, read Trait1 Trait2 <<< ${ARRAY[j]}
    printf "%s\n%s\n" "$Trait1" "$Trait2"
done
```